# AWS Glue - IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate value for path

Tags: python, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have a messy data source where some field values can come in with two different names but should map to one conformed field name on the output.

e.g. data source contains `update_date` or `modified_date` and both should map to `timestamp`.

Both field names are never present simultaneously on the same row of data.

The glue script looks like this. Some lines have been redacted for clarity:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node Data Catalog table
DataCatalogtable_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="mydb",
    table_name="crawl_rawdata",
    transformation_ctx="DataCatalogtable_node1",
)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=DataCatalogtable_node1,
    mappings=[
        ...
        ("update_date", "string", "timestamp", "string"),
        ...
        ("modified_date", "string", "timestamp", "string"),
        ...
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="orc",
    connection_options={
        "path": "s3://mybucket/data-lake/glue/",
        "compression": "snappy",
        "partitionKeys": [ ... ],
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the information about the line that is provoking this error? You can find it in AWS logs. I also experienced the same error. In my case, the solution was just replacing a variable with a list of strings with this list of strings. Let me show you a piece of code:

```
#This raises the IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate value for path
list_of_columns = ["col_a","col_b"]
data.select_fields(list_of_columns)

#This raises no error
data.select_fields( ["col_a","col_b"])
```